# Alembic online mode FATAL: database does not exist

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-redshift, alembic

I am using `alembic` and when I run `alembic upgrade head`

It returns: `sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) FATAL:  database "my_db'" does not exist`

My config file has the following url:

```
sqlalchemy.url = redshift+psycopg2://user:pwd@MY_REDSHIFT_HOSTNAME:5439/my_db'
```

I modified my `run_migrations_online` function to allow ssl:

```
def run_migrations_online():
"""Run migrations in 'online' mode.

In this scenario we need to create an Engine
and associate a connection with the context.

"""
connectable = engine_from_config(
    config.get_section(config.config_ini_section),
    prefix="sqlalchemy.",
    poolclass=pool.NullPool,
    connect_args={'sslmode': 'prefer'}
)

with connectable.connect() as connection:
    context.configure(
        connection=connection, target_metadata=target_metadata
    )

    with context.begin_transaction():
        context.run_migrations()
```

Answer (score 2):

As explained by [@zzzeek](https://github.com/zzzeek) in [this issue](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/alembic/issues/614), alembic does not handle the creation of the database. However, not knowing your project structure, I'd say the easiest way to solve your problem would be this:

Add the following code to your `base.py` file (where you have defined the SQLAlchemy `engine` and `declarative_base`):

```py
from sqlalchemy_utils import create_database, database_exists

def validate_database():
    if not database_exists(engine.url):
        create_database(engine.url)
```

Note that you'll need to install the `sqlalchemy_utils` package using:

```sh
pip install sqlalchemy-utils
```

Now, in your `env.py` module, import the newly created `validate_database` function and call it:

```py
from my_app.db_models.base import validate_database

validate_database()
```

Hope this solves your problem!

P.S. I've borrowed from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56162489/5863877) as well.